# How to build apk for two architectures

Tags: apportable

I'm trying to build apk for armeabi and armv7a architectures. I'm using following parameters for this.

```
 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi UNIVERSAL_APK=yes CHILD_ARCH_ABIS=armv7a BUILD=release EXPANSION_FILES=yes EXPANSION_FILES_BUNDLE=yes apportable
```

It's builds fine. But after upload to play store it detects only armeabi. Is it possible build apk for two architectures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last apportable version (release_1.1.10) it works perfect

```
 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi UNIVERSAL_APK=yes CHILD_ARCH_ABIS=armv7a,x86 BUILD=release EXPANSION_FILES=yes EXPANSION_FILES_BUNDLE=yes apportable
```